# How to import only some data files but ignore others?

Tags: matlab, import

I have 48 1000x28 data files, (no headers, strings or special characters) which I'd like to import in 4 batches of 12.
In the first batch the files have names:

**spread_YAB_4ACH_caretype_??_model_1** *`where ??=1:6`*

The second batch

**spread_YAB_4ACH_caretype_??_MC_model_1** where again *`??=1:6`*
I'm not sure where to put the wildcard *

```
D = dir('spread_YAB_4ACH_caretype_*_model_1.txt');
 dummy=zeros(1000,length(D));

for k=1:length(D)
   file = num2str(D(k).name);
 fid=fopen(file);
   myCell = textscan (fid, '%f');
   dummydummy=reshape(cell2mat(myCell(:,end)),1000,28); %#cell makes one column vector, why?
   dummy(:,k)=dummydummy(:,end);                        %# Only want last column
 fclose(fid);
end
```

This script looks an awful mess, surely you don't need this much bumpf to import a group of simple data files. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by _import_?

Comment: read in 1000 data points from the end column of 48 .txt files, and place them consecutively into a dummy array for further calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d=dir(foldername); %#That is where your files are
for i=3:1:length(d) %#ignore the . and ..
    if strfind(d(i,1).name,'MC_model')
         %#some code to do with the file of the second batch#%
    else
        %some code to do with the file of the first batch#%
    end
end
```

Comment: That sorts out the wildcard bit. But how would you sequentially insert the columns into a dummy array? ie all MC_model columns in columns 1:6 and all non_MC_model columns in columns 7:12?

Comment: Ah one thing, can I use logical operators in strfind? ie `strfind(d(i,1).name,'MC_model'~&'4ACH')`?

Comment: strfind is used for finding one string in another, you may use this twice as in (strfind(d(i,1).name,'MC_model')&(strfind(second condition))

Comment: How about AND NOT ie, files that contain model_1 but NOT MC_model?

Comment: then you can say (strfind(d(i,1).name,'model_1')&(~strfind(d(i,1).name,'MC_model')

Comment: But then the filename: spread_YAB_4ACH_caretype_1_model_1 should fit the last criteria:  (strfind(d(i,1).name,'model_1')&(~strfind(d(i,1).name,'MC_model') but it matlab says it doesnt, is there something wrong with the logical operator here?

Comment: strfind returns [] if nothing is found, thus ~ won't work here.  Maybe try strfind(d(i,1).name,'model_1')&isempty(strfind(d(i,1).name,'MC_model'))